# Удаляются файлы после обновления приложения

Tags: java, android

Сохраняю файлы в директорию приложения, но почему то после обновления приложения они удаляются. Подскажите как это можно исправить?

```
try {
    final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyGen.initialize(4096, new SecureRandom());
    final KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();


    File privateKeyFile = new File(this.getFilesDir().toString() + "/" + md5(nickname.getText().toString() + password.getText().toString()) + "_private_key");
    File publicKeyFile = new File(this.getFilesDir().toString() + "/" + md5(nickname.getText().toString() + password.getText().toString()) + "_public_key");


    if (privateKeyFile.getParentFile() != null) {
        privateKeyFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
    privateKeyFile.createNewFile();

    if (publicKeyFile.getParentFile() != null) {
        publicKeyFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
    publicKeyFile.createNewFile();

    BufferedWriter pubOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(publicKeyFile)));
    pubOut.write(byte2Hex(key.getPublic().getEncoded()));
    pubOut.flush();
    pubOut.close();

    BufferedWriter privOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFile)));
    privOut.write(byte2Hex(key.getPrivate().getEncoded()));
    privOut.flush();
    privOut.close();

    open_key_global = key.getPublic().toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("TAG123", "Ключи шифрования не были созданы");
}
```

Comment: они не должны удаляться. Вы пробовали посмотреть при помощи root?